# .htaccess redirect second level pages to third level pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect everything under `https://example.com/work/` to `https://example.com/work/john/`.

This is what I've done:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^work/(.*)$ work/john/$1 [L,R=301]
```

While testing, the url: `https://example.com/work/design/download`

gets redirected to:

`https://example.com/work/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/john/design/download`.

Chrome gives me the error: *ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this rule with a negative lookahead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^work/(?!(?:sam|john)(?:/|$))(.*)$ work/john/$1 [L,R=301,NE,NC]
```

`(?!john(?:/|$))` is a negative lookahead that skips redirect when `john/` or `john` comes right after `/work/` in URI.

Make sure to completely clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: That seems to work. However, there is one small issue. The subpages seem to redirect fine but the page `/work/john` is still trying to redirect to `/work/john/john`. This time it is a "page not found" error. Another question: is it possible to prevent another subfolder from redirecting? For example, I don't want anything under`/work/sam` to redirect.